# echo, printf not work in script when run it as command

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I test the script in WSL2
Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "testing..."
printf "testing..."
```

It work fine if I run like
`bash test`
`source test`
`. test`

But it output nothing if I add the path the script located in to PATH and run
`test`

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: `test` is a standard utility (also known as `[`)

Comment: Show output of `type test`.

Comment: lol, thk for answer. It works after I modify its file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is a bash built-in. POSIX systems will also have a `test` executable.

When you enter a command without specifying a path to the executable, bash will first check if the command is one of its built-in commands before searching for the executable in the `PATH`. If the command matches the name of one of the bash built-ins, it will run the built-in.

If you still want to run your script *without* specifying its path, there are two ways to do it:

1. **Recommended:** Rename your file, and then run it with its new name (your script file needs to have its executable permission bit(s) set).
2. Make sure your script has its file permissions set so that it is executable, make sure your `PATH` is set up so that your `test` will be found before the system's `test`, and then run `env test` to run your script. `env` will search your `PATH` to find your `test` executable, and then it will execute it.

Ultimately, option 2 is not recommended, because it can be brittle to reorder your `PATH`, and it can be confusing (for you and for others) to have a second `test` binary on your system.

Comment: I wouldn't say "bash utility" -- `/usr/bin/test` exists even if you don't have bash installed at all; that bash provides a builtin equivalent is a performance optimization, but behavior would be identical if it didn't.